# Convert a fraction into a whole number and a binary exponent (eg 3.125 => 25, 3)

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have a function which takes one argument, a fraction, and returns two numbers - an **integer** and a **power of two**.

- So, when you divide the the **integer** by 2 raised to power **power of two**, you get the original number. For example, When I run `get_whole_number(Math.PI)`, I get **`884279719003555` and `48`** since `884279719003555/(2**48)` is close to `Math.PI`.
- `get_whole_number(0.5)` => `1, 1`

```js
function get_whole_number(number, exponent=0) {
    if(number%1 == 0) return [number, exponent];
    exponent++;
    number *= 2;
    if(exponent >= 150) return [Math.round(number), exponent];
    return get_whole_number(number, exponent);
};

console.time("timer");
let x = get_whole_number(0.1);
console.timeEnd("timer");

console.log(x);
```

**Is this a good way of writing such a function? Or will it be better if I use bitwise operations rather than `modulo` and `round()`?**

Note: numbers which are irrational in binary will not be represented 100% exactly with this notation, but they are close enough.

Comment: You are hopefully aware that floating point numbers are merely an approximation. Floating point deviations will be enlarged and so on. A typed language might be better, should you run into problems.

Comment: @JoopEggen " floating point numbers are merely an approximation." --> Detail: All finite floating point numbers are _exact_.  It is the code we use that often results in an answer that is an approximation to the math one.  Done right, OP's goal is possible with an exactly correct answer when starting with a floating point number.  Of course not all textual decimal numbers have a FP encoding.

Comment: @chux the set of all floating point numbers does neither correspond with decimal representations, nor is closed to a large degree for all operations. I agree, one could come to some solution. But it is like bookkeeping with Roman numbers: ii+ii=iv; xii/iv=iii.

Answer (score 1):

- `get_whole_number` looks like a misnomer. The function does not *get a whoe number*. Rather, it deconstructs the float into a mantissa and exponent, and returns both. `deconstruct_float` could be better. Even better is to reuse the names for the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard library, e.g. `frexp, frexpf, frexpl` (I don't know wether [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) may tell a `float` from `double` from `long double`).
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) does not support tail recursion optimization. `if(exponent >= 150)` means that the recursion could be up to 150 levels deep. Better eliminate it manually:

  ```
    function get_whole_number(number, exponent=0) {
        while (number%1 != 0 && exponent < 150) (
          exponent++;
          number *= 2;
        }

        if(exponent >= 150) {
            number = Math.round(number);
        }
        return [number, exponent];
    };
  ```
- Assuming IEEE-574 format, check out [this article](https://blog.codefrau.net/2014/08/deconstructing-floats-frexp-and-ldexp.html) for the right implementation.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript style notes

- In JS we use `camelCase` when creating variable names. Avoid using `snake_case`
- Put spaces between operators.
- Delimit all code blocks with `{}`.
- Dont add `;` at end of function.
- Use strict equality `===` rather than `==`

The name `number` does not convay the functions intent as well as it could. Maybe the name `fraction` whould be better.

### Bug

If I call the function incorrectly `getWholeNumber(10, 5)` it returns the wrong result `[10, 5]`.

Should be `[10, 0]`

### JavaScript and Recursion

JavaScript has a limited call stack space (and no tail calling). Any recursive function greatly increases the risk of throwing a call stack overflow error.

Avoid recursion when possible.

#### Recursion overheads

Most often using a loop will also give a significant performance increase over recursion as there is no need to capture the function's state and push and pull it from the call stack.

The rewrite does a performance comparison. The performance difference will depend on the number you are processing. The example uses square root of 2 with 52 iterations to complete. The non-recursive function is ~ twice as fast

### Rewrite

The rewrite include a performance comparison that runs a recursive and while loop version to compare performance.

The function `getWholeNumber` is a rewrite of your original code with a fix for the bug. It can not start with the wrong value of exponent.

The function `wholeNumber` uses a while loop rather than recursion.

The Performance test runs the function many times in batches. The tests are complex and not part of the answer apart from just providing a reliable comparison.

On faster devices the test may restart several time as it calibrates to the unknown timer resolution.

See comments for more details on how the performance test works.

```js
// Recursive version
function getWholeNumber(fraction) {
    return getWholeNumber(fraction, 0);
    function getWholeNumber(fraction, exponent) {
        if (fraction % 1 === 0) { return [fraction, exponent] }
        exponent++;
        fraction *= 2;
        if (exponent >= 150) { return [Math.round(fraction), exponent] }
        return getWholeNumber(fraction, exponent);
    }
}

// Using while loop,
function wholeNumber(fraction) {
    var exponent = 0;
    for (; exponent < 150; exponent++) {
        if (fraction % 1 === 0) { return [fraction, exponent] }
        fraction *= 2;
    }
    return [Math.round(fraction), exponent];
}






/* Performance testing code */
const frac = Math.SQRT2;  // Test input value
const tests = 100;        // Number of cycles. Time is measured over cycle
var testCycles = 50;      // Tests per cycle
const timerResolution = 0.02; // In ms resolution of performance now time.
                          // This can be as low as 0.001ms. However FireFox can be up to
                          // 0.1ms and Chrome 0.02ms
const coolDownTime = 100; // ms between test cycles
                          // If you hear fans speeding up during test increase 
                          // cool down time. CPU may be throttled when cooling fans 
                          // start up and could introduce a performance bias. 
const warmupCount = 20;   // This lets the optimize get a good look at the running
                          // code before we start timing the function
const times = [0, 0];     // Holds total times in ms;
var restart = false;
var cycles = 0;           // Counts cycles. 

restarter();               // Starts performance test and
function restarter() {     // restarts if there is a time resolution error
    container.classList.toggle("error", false);
    restart = false;
    cycles = -warmupCount;
    times[0] = times[1] = 0;
    test();
}
function resolutionError(time) {
    const timeFix = Math.max(timerResolution * 0.2, time);
    testCycles = Math.ceil(testCycles * (timerResolution / timeFix)) + 20;
    restart = true;            
    log.textContent = "Timer resolution ERROR!!!. Cycles reset to: " + testCycles;
    logA.textContent = "Time " + time + "ms per " + testCycles + " calls";
    container.classList.toggle("error", true);
}

function runTest(func, val) {  
    var i = 0;
    const now = performance.now();
    for(; i < testCycles; i++) { func(val) }
    const time = performance.now() - now;
    if (time < timerResolution) { resolutionError(time) } 
    return time;
}
function test() {
    if (cycles < tests) {        
        if (cycles === 0) { times[0] = times[1] = 0 }
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) { // Avoid optimizor and CPU throttling bias 
                                   // by changing call order
            times[0] += runTest(wholeNumber, frac);
            times[1] += runTest(getWholeNumber, frac);
        } else {
            times[1] += runTest(getWholeNumber, frac);
            times[0] += runTest(wholeNumber, frac);
        }

        if (restart) {
           logB.textContent = "Timer resolution Error";
           setTimeout(restarter, 1000);    
           return;
        } 
        if (cycles < 0) {
            log.textContent = "Warm-up count down: " + cycles;
        } else {
            log.textContent = ((cycles / tests) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%  complete";
            logA.textContent = "While loop time: " + times[0].toFixed(1) + "ms";
            logB.textContent = "Recursive time:  " + times[1].toFixed(1) + "ms";
        }
        cycles ++;
        setTimeout(test, coolDownTime);
    } else {
        log.textContent =  "Completed " + (cycles * testCycles) + " tests";
        logA.textContent = "While loop total time: " + times[0].toFixed(1) + "ms Mean: " + 
            (times[0] / (tests * testCycles)).toFixed(5) + "ms per call";
        logB.textContent = "Recursive total time:  " + times[1].toFixed(1) + "ms Mean: " + 
            (times[1] / (tests * testCycles)).toFixed(5) + "ms per call";

        console.log("While loop result:     " + wholeNumber(frac));
        console.log("Recursive loop result: " + getWholeNumber(frac));
    }
}
```

```css
#container {
   width: 80%;
   border: 2px solid green;
   padding: 4px;
}
.error {
   border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<code id="log" ></code><br>
<code id="logA"></code><br>
<code id="logB"></code>
</div>
```

Comment: *Should be [10, 0]* - that would be wrong because you passed `10` with binary exponent `5` into the function, which is `320` and not `10`. Explanation: `10*2**5 = 320 ≠ 10*2**0`. I really like the idea of the for loop increasing the exponent though, I didn't think of that.

Comment: And as for semicolons after function declarations, it was a mistake, because I'm used to declaring functions as expressions, which is a statement. I appreciate that normal declaration however is not a statement.

Comment: @AlphaHowl  Using the comment as correct with [10,5] correctly returning [10,5] The result of `get_whole_number(2.5, 2)` returns [5,3]` one expects [10,0]  With either expectation (answer or comment) the `exponent` is being incorrectly handled if given in some situations.

Comment: yeah, you're right. Originally though, I only created the argument `exponent=0` just so that the recursion would work. It was not designed to be passed into the function at the first recursion (ie by the user), only after that by the function itself.

Comment: Also, I would like to ask one last question: is there an advantage of using pascal case or camel case over snake case? Does it cause any errors, or is it just a standard expectation of other programmers who may want to read my code?

Comment: I had a read of some sites, notably [this one](https://betterprogramming.pub/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841), where it says *There is no best method of combining words. The main thing is to be consistent*, and *This style [snake_case], when capitalized, is often used as a convention in declaring constants in many languages. When lower cased, it is used conventionally in declaring database field names*. I prefer snake case for functions and important variables, and I am consisten with this.

Comment: @AlphaHowl You can use any naming style you wish. `camelCase` is the style used by the JS API's.

Answer (score 0):

This is only from a *floating point* point-of-view.

---

The 150 in `if(exponent >= 150)` is a unqualified magic number.

[binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can encode values with greater exponent needs like 1.0*2<sup>-1074</sup>.  Perhaps use:

```
if (exponent >= 1074)
```

---

I suggest testing with the usual edge case suspects:

```
0.0  
-0.0                     // minus 0
2.2250738585072014E-308  // Smallest non-zero normal
4.9406564584124654E-324  // Smallest non-zero
1.7976931348623157E+308  // Max
-1.7976931348623157E+308 // Min
NaN                      // Some not-a-number (tricky to set this one up)
```

Perhaps some random numbers too.

```
42.0                     // The answer to everything
-4442                    // AKA 867-5309
```

---

> Note: numbers which are irrational in binary will not be represented 100% exactly with this notation, but they are close enough.

Note that all binary64 finite values are *rational*.

I think OP wanted something like: "numbers which are not exactly repeatable in binary will not ... "

[irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) has a differnt meaning.